# Insufficient Privileges when running report

Tags: reporting, administration

I have a report running on Account. One of the users have access to the folder but not the report. The users profile has read, create, edit, viewall for account.

I am quite baffled as to what is causing this.

Comment: Is this the standard Accounts report type? or is custom? Is the account the only object in that report type?

Comment: could be silly suggestion, check if you saved the report in "My personal folder".

Comment: What differences are there between these users? Are they the same Profile and Role?

Answer (score 2):

If You are using Custom Report Type for Report Make sure it is "Deployed"

Answer (score 1):

The report is most likely accessing some information that the specified profile/user does not have access to, which raises the "insufficient privileges" error.

- Check field level security for all fields that are referenced in the report.

  - Setup->Security Controls->Field Accessibility->Account->View by profile
- Check that the user/profile has access to any other objects that are referenced in the report.

  - Setup->Manage Users->Profiles->[Profile]->Object Settings